# Mqtt publishing/payload doesn't show up from JSON

Tags: c#, json, mqtt, payload

I have a form and I want to publish the message from the JSON part. but I get this error: `Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object` (e.g. `{"name":"value"})` into type `System.Collections.Generic.List1[WindowsFormsApplication1.Form2+jsonlist]` because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. `[1,2,3]`) to deserialize correctly.

To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. `[1,2,3]`) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or `List<T>`) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. `JsonObjectAttribute` can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.

Path 'html', line 1, position 8.

Code:

```
    static void client_MqttMsgPublishReceived(object sender, MqttMsgPublishEventArgs e)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(e.Message));


        var json5 = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(e.Message);
        List<jsonlist> jsons = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<jsonlist>>(json5);

        foreach (jsonlist dets2 in jsons)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dets2.plaintext);
        }
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        MqttClient client = new MqttClient(IPAddress.Parse("85.17.193.165"));
        client.MqttMsgPublishReceived += client_MqttMsgPublishReceived;

        string clientId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        client.Connect(clientId);

        Console.WriteLine("isconn:" + client.IsConnected);

        client.Subscribe(new string[] { "/doorbell/listen" }, new byte[] { MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_AT_MOST_ONCE  });
    }
```

class :

```
    public class jsonlist
    {

        public string plaintext { get; set; }
        public string link { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: Please post the exact json string (`json5` variable) you are trying to deserialize. Anyway, from code looks like you are receiving the payload and not publishing it.

Comment: @AlessandroDaRugna var json5 = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(e.Message);

Comment: We'd like to see the string **value**: `Console.WriteLine(json5)`